# iOS Enterprise Distribution - iPod 5th gen not recognized as 4 inch

Tags: ios, resolution, ipod-touch, enterprise-distribution

The title pretty much says it all. I am distributing an OpenGL ES-based app in-house, using Enterprise Distribution program, to non-provisioned devices. The app will ultimately be distributed on the AppStore, but we are using the Enterprise program to overcome the 100 devices limitation and have our employees test the app on their own iOS devices mid-development.

Some of the devices are iPads, others are iPhone 4S, others are iPhone 5, and a there is two 5th generation iPod touch devices.

The app bundles the required Default-568h@2x.png launch image necessary to be recognized as "4 inch ready" at build/runtime. The SDK used is 6 (Xcode 4) and now 7 (Xcode 5).

When I install the app on iPhone 5 devices through the Organizer (after archiving/exporting an .ipa), it launches in 4-inch mode (320x568) with no problems.

But on the iPod touch 5th gen (2 devices total), the app launches with black bars above and below. Since the iPod touch devices are not registered/provisioned in the developer program, I can not debug the app so I can't tell for sure what's happening inside the code. But placing logs and/or alert views tells me the app thinks the view is 320x480 (`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` returns that size).

Anyone experienced the same problem? Any pointers/advise?